# Structuring components representing a little bit more complicated data. Store vs props vs one component

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I would like to create component, that allows user to edit some mathematical classification model data.

Interface may look like.

```
interface MathModel {
  name: string;
  article: ArticleDescription;
  criteria: Criteria;
  coefficients: Coefficient[];
  interpretation: ResultInterpretation;
}

interface Coefficient {
   value: number; // never equal to 0! how to validate?
}

interface  Interpretation
{
   description: string
   interpretationItems: InterpretationItem[]
   // ...
}

interface InterpretationItem {
  scoreMin: number
  scoreMax: number
}
```

In the first attempt I tried to create separate components to handle each property of `MathModel` For instance:  `MathModelCoefficientList`, `MathModelInterpretation`  components.

But interpretation component needs extra knowledge, that is not property of Interpretation type. It needs to know sum of all values of coefficients.
It is because InterpretationItem scoreMax should not be greater then sum of coefficients.

Also InterpretationItems are not independent - Each InterpretationItem should represent different score interval.

So there can't be simple v-model components.

Possible solutions:

1. Inside `MathModelComponent` create computed variable

```
const coefficientsValuesSum = computed( () => ...)

const nonOverlapingInteretationItems = ...
```

then

`<MathModelInterpretation v-model=modelValue.interpretation :coefficientsValuesSum=coefficientsValuesSum :nonOverlapingInteretationItems=nonOverlapingInteretationItems>`

`<MathModelInterpretationList v-model=modelValue.interpretationItems :coefficientsValuesSum=coefficientsValuesSum :nonOverlapingInteretationItems=nonOverlapingInteretationItems>`

`<MathModelInterpretationItem v-model=modelValue[i] :coefficientsValuesSum=coefficientsValuesSum :nonOverlapingInteretationItems=nonOverlapingInteretationItems[i]>`

It is nice that we can see dependencies of subcomponents but I have doubts about playing with so many props.

2. Create store that holds MathModel. Dependencies are less visible. Additionally -
   is it is okay to pass to component index by which it will fetch data from store?

`<MathModelInterpretationItem :intepretationItemIdx=i>`

3. It is not so complex component. Do not divide it. Keep Everything In One Component.

Extra:

Extra 1) Validation. After division to subcomponents it is trickier to validate before submit. Right?

Extra 2)  I could write typescript class MathModel with method `sumAllCoefficientValues()`. How to connect typescript classes and their methods with Vue reactivity system? Is there any sense?

Comment: `<MathModelInterpretation v-model=modelValue.interpretation` - shouldn't be this way. You shouldn't mutate a prop (modelValue), should be done in a parent. So this makes putting all things together into a single object impractical. "is it is okay to pass to component index" - depends on where these indices originate from, but in case there's no specific order, it's not a good idea, will be harder to debug at least

Comment: @EstusFlask thank you for your comment. It seems I made big error in simplifying. I actually use `const data = useVModel(props, 'modelValue', emit)` from https://vueuse.org/core/usevmodel/ so it should look: `<MathModelInterpretation v-model=data.interpretation` is it right now?

Comment: Not really, v-model=data.interpretation still mutates data object. With this composable you'd need separate useVModel for interpretation, etc props instead of containing them in a single model object. See https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#mutating-object-array-props

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification! "So this makes putting all things together into a single object impractical" -> you mean in `MathModel` should never be modelValue of any component? There should be components handling properties of `MathModel`? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, it's unclear what's the use for it in your app but it will likely be more convenient to keep interpretation, etc as separate states and merge them at some point when needed. So there will be named v-models like `v-model:interpretation="interpretation"`, and useVModel can be used for them in nested comps. But it's still possible that a store is applicable here

Comment: According to https://blog.logrocket.com/using-v-model-vue-3-build-complex-forms/ in *special cases* parent component we can have object as field - but not as prop (back to the problem of mutability of prop). In Parent component  `<AddressFieldGroup v-model:streetName="form.deliveryAddress.streetName" .../>`;  the other issue is that v-model:variable variable should be passed by value? (i.e. not be an object)?

Comment: That it's suggested in some article doesn't make it acceptable, but I see no problems here. Notice that AddressFieldGroup does `$emit('update:postcode', $event.target.value)`. The point is that a child shouldn't mutate an object that was passed to it from a parent. Instead it should ask a parent to mutate and pass the updated object back through a prop. In this case this is done through conventional v-model `update:` event but could be any other. The same for a grandchild. This is how two-way binding works in Vue. Not doing that leads to convoluted and potentially erroneous data flow.

Comment: So the solution is to avoid to pass javascript objects as a props? W suppose that cloning props in child component is not the advised practice. What in case if our data model is represented by deeply nested objects?

Comment: No, you can pass them freely, but not mutate them inside a child like `v-model=data.interpretation`. You can clone a prop if needed but this depends on the purpose

Answer (score 0):

Huge thanks to Estus Flask for clarification of a trap behind mutating object properties and arrays.
Still I do not what is proper way of writing component that handles list of objects.
Imagine list of coefficients that are more complicated:

Recap MathModel type:

```
interface MathModel {
  coefficients: Coefficient[];
  //...
}
```

```
interface Coefficient {
   value: number;
   x: number;
   y: number;
   yetAnotherProperty: SomeObject;
}
```

MathModel.vue

```
<template>
 ...
 <CoefficientsList :mathModel.coefficients >
<template>
```

So how `CoefficientsList` should let parent `MathModel` component know about change of some property of element of passed array? How `CoefficientsList` can guarantee immutability of each element of array passed as prop, especially that array contains nested objects?

The first solution that I can imagine is that `CoefficientsList` makes deep copy of prop array and emit event with callback containing changed deep copy.
In this solution we could even use `v-model`:

`<CoefficientsList v-model:mathModel.coefficients>`

This involves making deep copy, passing possibly big payload in callback. Also - we should watch for any change in deep copy to emit `update:modelValue`  Anything else?

Another option that I was thinking about is to let parent mutate its state by receiving events like that:
`elementChange(newElement, index)`, `elementRemoved(index)`
But actually since new `Coefficient` type is nested probably there would be need to deep copy anyway (since I would like to v-model `coefficient[index].yetAnotherProperty` to `YetAnotherComponent` or so).